# How to convert magnitudes to bolometric luminosity?

Tags: luminosity

If we know a star's magnitudes from several bands(say u,g,r,i,z,J,H,k) and the star's distance, how to calculate Lbol?

Let's suppose the star has a black body spectrum. Is there any manual about the calculation? It's better to have a lot of technical details.

Comment: Are you looking​ for something more complicated than find a bolometric correction?

Comment: @Rob yes, these objects are cool and bright in infrared, but I know their magnitudes from 2MASS and WISE, and even Sloan. Convert magnitudes to flux and fit using a blackbody model  is enough?

Comment: They are certainly not blackbodies. You would need to fit with proper stellar models.

Comment: @Rob  If we know magnitudes and stellar type, how to calculate Lbol?

Comment: @Rob Do you know any table like this (https://sites.uni.edu/morgans/astro/course/Notes/section2/spectraltemps.html)? Perhaps a table is a more direct way for me, but spectral types are sort of sparse especially for cool objects in this table.

Comment: @Rob A table(especially for cool objects) does not appear in that question.

Comment: I have added a reference to a relevant table for cool objects.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Wikipedia,

> The bolometric magnitude Mbol, takes into account electromagnetic
>   radiation at all wavelengths. It includes those unobserved due to
>   instrumental pass-band, the Earth's atmospheric absorption, and
>   extinction by interstellar dust. It is defined based on the luminosity
>   of the stars. In the case of stars with few observations, it must be
>   computed assuming an effective temperature. Classically, the
>   difference in bolometric magnitude is related to the luminosity ratio
>   according to:

$ M_{bol,*} - M_{bol,sun} = -2.5log_{10}(\frac{L_*}{L_{sun}})$

> In August 2015, the International Astronomical Union passed Resolution
>   B2[7] defining the zero points of the absolute and apparent bolometric
>   magnitude scales in SI units for power (watts) and irradiance (W/m2),
>   respectively. Although bolometric magnitudes had been used by
>   astronomers for many decades, there had been systematic differences in
>   the absolute magnitude-luminosity scales presented in various
>   astronomical references, and no international standardization. This
>   led to systematic differences in bolometric corrections scales, which
>   when combined with incorrect assumed absolute bolometric magnitudes
>   for the Sun could lead to systematic errors in estimated stellar
>   luminosities (and stellar properties calculated which rely on stellar
>   luminosity, such as radii, ages, and so on).

[leading to the accepted definition of]
$ M_{bol} = -2.5log_{10}(L_*) + 71.1974... $ , where the constant term is the zero-point luminosity $L_0$ .

Dunno if this helps, other than that you have to determine the spectral luminosity of the star in question.